# sam package vs aws cloudformation package

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild, aws-sam

[The](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-deploying.html#serverless-sam-cli-using-package-and-deploy) docs say they do exactly the same thing:

> Both the sam package and sam deploy commands described in this section
>   are identical to their AWS CLI equivalent commands aws cloudformation
>   package and aws cloudformation deploy, respectively.

But my experience suggests that isn't quite true. When I run `sam deploy` for my Java-based Lambda gets an artifact uploaded to S3 with this type of zip structure:

- META-INF
- com/example/etc, class files
- logback.groovy, other resources
- lib, which contains all my jars

And this executes nicely in Lambda. But when I follow the [Lambda + CodePipeline docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/build-pipeline.html) and use  `aws cloudformation`, I get this zip structure (which is essentially my git repo):

- README.md
- build/
- build.gradle
- buildspec.yml
- events
- gradle/
- gradlew
- gradlew.bat
- src/
- template.yml

Note: this alternative structure happens even outside of CodeBuild, so I am doubtful it has anything to do with what is in `buildspec.yml`. I can reproduce the two structures simply by invoking the two different package commands on my desktop.

Any ideas why there is a difference? I'd like to understand it, especially since the docs say they should be the same, before I switch my `buildspec.yml` to use `sam deploy`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'sam package' is as dumb as 'aws cloudformation package'. The difference come from 'sam build' which will build a new 'template.yaml' and place under '{app_dir}/.aws-sam/build/template.yaml with the dependencies.

This new 'template.yaml' is used by 'sam package' (instead of '{app_dir}/template.yaml') thus adding the required dependencies in the package. Please investigate the directory '{app_dir}/.aws-sam/build/' to learn more.

If you run 'cloudformation package' in the directory '{app_dir}/.aws-sam/build' you will get the same result as 'sam package'.

Use 'sam package' with --debug to see which template file it is reading:

```
$ sam package --output-template-file packaged.yaml --s3-bucket {bucket_name} --debug
Using SAM Template at /home/ec2-user/sam-app/.aws-sam/build/template.yaml
```

'aws cloudformation package' will just read the template file from where you specify:

```
$ aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yaml --output-template-file packaged.yaml --s3-bucket {my-bucket}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with `aws cloudformation package ...` which did not update the `DefinitionUri` to a corresponding S3 URI of the SAM template I had as follows for a Step function:

```
DemoStepFunction:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
      Properties:
        DefinitionUri: stepfunctions/demo_step_1.json
```

`sam package...` solved the problem and created the correct Cloudformation template:

```
  DemoStepFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
    Properties:
      DefinitionUri:
        Bucket: pipeline-demo-test1
        Key: cassdasd6565casdawwebf5f3
```